# Microsofts File Checksum Integrity Verifier utility: How to exclude directories

Tags: windows

I've been using the FCIV from Microsoft to generate hashes of files (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290)

But I just cannot figure out how I can exclude directories or files.

The site link has this example:

```
fciv.exe c:\ -r -exc exceptions.txt -sha1 -xml dbsha.xml
```

But there is no information about how to write those exceptions.
I've tried to put `e:\temp\dummy` and indexed `e:\temp`. I've seen fciv reading this file in but it ignores anything in this file and says nothing about the syntax.
I've tried

```
*
dummy
*dummy*
e:\temp\dummy
```

Nothing works.

The web has nothing on this tool. [This thread](http://www.winvistatips.com/threads/fciv.409938/) has the same question and an unreadable answer.

However I would like to define exceptions to the db file when **creating** the database because fciv keeps chewing forever on files I will never use anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WOW!  There is NO documentation on this anywhere.

The execution example would be:

```
fciv -r -exc IGNOREFILE.txt C:\
```

The IGNOREFILE.txt:

```
\NAME_OF_DIRECTORY(make sure to carriage return at end)
```

That worked for me.  If you don't add the carriage return it won't work, don't know why.